# Is this black stuff behind our medicine cabinet mold?

Tags: bathroom, mold

We removed our medicine cabinet in our bathroom in preparation for painting and discovered this water stain accompanied by some black specks. The water stain strongly suggests that this might be mold but I'm hoping it might be something else. Is it mold?

[image: water stain behind medicine cabinet]

[image: black spots behind medicine cabinet]

Comment: Cannot tell mold from a picture, only by testing.  If those small black marks are all there is, a wash down with some bleach or vinegar should be all that is needed to kill it, no testing needed.

Comment: @crip659 Got it. There was some more spots (in the very top right of the first picture) so I was afraid that there was more of it inside the walls.

Comment: There might be, but mold usually is on the surface.  Would need to check inside of the walls if any moisture/water got in.  Cameras for checking in tight spaces are quite cheap these days and only need small holes.